# What is perpetual sleep?

Tags: jeremiah

Jeremiah 51:57
I will make drunk her officials and her wise men, her governors, her commanders, and her warriors; they shall sleep a perpetual sleep and not wake, declares the King, whose name is the LORD of hosts.

Comment: If "sleep" means death, then the thing about them not waking up would have to refer to them not taking part in the bodily resurrection.

Comment: Yet, John 5:28-28 demands: Marvel not at this: for the hour is coming, in the which **all that are in the graves** shall hear his voice, And shall come forth; they that have done good, unto **the resurrection of life**; and they that have done evil, unto **the resurrection of damnation**.

Comment: Some Bible translations, like NIV, have: from their graves "rise to life". And: from their graves "rise to be condemned". The first thing to rise out of a grave logically has to be a ghost. Thus, it is ghosts that rise out of the graves; some to life (in a new body), and some to "damnation", which would be the opposite to life.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jer 51 is a prophecy about God's judgement to fall (one day) on Babylon.  The chapter contains two verses with a very similar content/imagery:

- V39 - While they are flushed with heat, I will serve them a feast, and I will make them drunk so that they may revel; then they will fall asleep forever and never wake up, declares the LORD. [V40 then describes in non-metaphoric language that God will "bring them down like lambs to the slaughter, like rams with male goats."]
- V57 - I will make her princes and wise men drunk, along with her governors, officials, and warriors.  Then they will fall asleep forever and not wake up,” declares the King, whose name is the LORD of Hosts.

The imagery is unmistakable - "fall asleep and not wake up" means that they are going to die.  Jesus & the NT used exactly the same idiom of sleep meaning death in several places such as Matt 9:24, 28:13, Mark 5:39, Luke 8:52, John 11:11, 12, Acts 7:60, 13:36, 1 Cor 7:39, 11:30, 15:6, 18, 20, 51, 1 Thess 4:13-15, 5:10, 2 Peter 3:4, etc.

Ellicott sums this well when he says (on Jer 51:39):

> (39) In their heat I will make their feasts . . .—The words are stern
> and bitter in their irony. When the revellers are hot with wine and
> lust (comp. Hosea 7:4-7) Jehovah would call them to a banquet of
> another kind. The wine cup which He would give them would be that of
> His wrath (Jeremiah 25:16-17), and their drunken joy should end in an
> eternal sleep. So Herodotus (i. 191) narrates that when Cyrus took the
> city by his stratagem the inhabitants were keeping a feast with their
> wonted revelry and license. (Compare Xenoph. Cyropœd. vii. 23.)